# fusioncharts giving render error on reload

Tags: vue.js

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

import axios from 'axios'

  Promise.all([
  axios.get(
    "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/data/dual-y-axis-data.json"
  ),
  axios.get(
    "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/schema/dual-y-axis-schema.json"
  )
]).then(function(res) {
    const data = res[0].data;
    const schema = res[1].data;

  const dataStore = new FusionCharts.DataStore();
  const dataSource = {
    chart: {
      multicanvas: false
    },
    caption: {
      text: "Energy & Temperature Measurements"
    },
    yaxis: [
      {
        plot: [
          {
            value: "Energy",
            connectnulldata: true,
            type: "line"
          }
        ],
        format: {
          suffix: " kWh"
        }
      },
      {
        plot: [
          {
            value: "Temperature",
            connectnulldata: true,
            type: "line"
          }
        ],
        format: {
          suffix: " °C"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  dataSource.data = dataStore.createDataTable(data, schema);

  new FusionCharts({
    type: "timeseries",
    renderAt: "chart-container",
    width: "100%",
    height: "500",
    dataSource: dataSource
  }).render();
});

</script>

<template>
    <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
</template>
```

This works perfectly fine when I make any changes to '.render()' for the first time but as soon as I reload its throwing an error saying that it cannot find a DOM element. Like if I change .render() to .render('') then it works and then I reload and it gives an error. I change it back to .render() and it works and then I reload and it doesnt work. How do I fix this?